# Identical situation different results! cannot watch youtube over proxy

Tags: proxy, socks, youtube

I use a socks5 proxy for daily Internet browsing to bypass Internet censors (actually it is a Windows application called freegate and I use it under Wine it doesn't need accounts or anything: it is free for China users). I use it on my both Linux laptops under Wine 1.6.2 and it was perfect until 3-4 days ago.  Now, on one of them, I cannot watch YouTube videos anymore, YouTube gives me "an error occurred, please try again later" for every single video.
freegate when first started generates an *.ini file that contains its configs.
I even copied the ini file from the one that YouTube works but it didn't work.

Here are the things I have done to get YouTube working again but did not work:

1. tried multiple browsers ex Chromium, Firefox, Google-chorme, Opera
2. tried flashplayer & html5
3. cleaned cache and cookies
4. changing dns
5. using the exact config on both pc
6. deleting ~/.wine folder to let wine rebuild a fresh one
7. installed unscd to clean dns cache!? and #/etc/init.d/unscd restart
8. changing socks proxy port
9. wait 3-4 days and hope it get fixed by itself
10. rebooting the system

Please note that I use the same version, same config — one of them opens YouTube great but the other one gives me "an error occurred, please try again later" for every single video

**any suggestions to fix this situation?**

Comment: just tried youtube-dl to see if its possible to download the video over proxy and IT worked problem should be related to browser or network cache!? also tried another proxy and it worked just fine but need to get freegate work because its a little faster

Answer (score 0):

Censorship is best avoided using a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network).

I can only suggest what I am using for this purpose and it's working flawlessly.

In my case I opted for [Private Internet Access](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/), but this is in no case an advertisement.

I can only speak from my experience:

1. No VPN traffic logs
2. Full censorship circumvention
3. Great price, starting from $3.33 / month if paid for a year
4. Payable with Bitcoin for better anonymity
5. They provide a great client for Linux